# Do any Christian denominations prohibit eating rare meat?

Tags: denomination-survey, diet

In comments on this question ..[What does it mean to abstain from blood in the 21st century?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46207/what-does-it-mean-to-abstain-from-blood-in-the-21st-century)... A user stated that Christians must not eat rare meat because doing so violates the command in Acts 15:28&29 (keep abstaining from blood)
I have not ever heard a person say:" make my steak well done I can't eat rare steak it is against my religion".
Are there denominations that prohibit members from eating meat that still shows traces of blood in it?

Comment: There maybe some Christian denominations who hold to the Old Testament views on the koshering of meat but that is not entirely relevant to the degree of rarity.

Comment: I think the heart of the question is "are there denominations that keep kosher".  The same reason we can eat pork applies here.

Comment: What happened to John hamptons answer?

Comment: @Pam It was deleted because it didn't mention anything about denomination that did or didn't have anything to say about this question. Ergo it was rightly flagged *Not An Answer*.

Comment: @Marc Comments are not the place to discuss the theology involved in isssues. If you have an answer post that, but please reserve the comment section for A) requesting clarification or B) suggesting improvements to posts.

Comment: @caleb I had asked Hampton to edit and state the denomination he was answering for the answer was  less than a day old

Comment: He can still edit and get it undeleted if it answers the question.

Comment: @caleb Okay I am not going to accept any answer as I am asking a viewpoint question I should just up vote the answers that are well written and referenced correct?

Comment: @Pam The correct answer to your question can only be "Yes, there are such denominations" or "No there aren't."  "My denomination believes X because Y" is not really an answer and "I believe X because Y" certainly is not.  There is no reason why there shouldn't be one right (accepted) answer - if the question was actually asking for multiple differing viewpoints, it would be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you google "Torah Christian", you may not find a **denomination**, *per se*, but you'll see several sites which support the notion that Christians must follow the Torah.

I have a friend who belongs to such a church (they're all "non-denominational", but loosely associate with each other) who maintains that Christians should not eat rare steak because there is still blood in it.

The problem with this stance is that, unless you are eating *truly* raw meat (eg off a freshly-killed rabbit before *any* cooking), there is [practically] no blood [left](http://www.factswt.com/did-you-know-that-the-red-juice-in-raw-red-meat-actually-isnt) in the meat, it's a combination of [water and myoglobin](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/04/the-red-juice-in-raw-red-meat-is-not-blood).

Myoglobin is functionally similar to hemoglobin, but stores oxygen in muscles vs blood, respectively.

There are all kinds of reasons to eat (or not eat) rare steak - that "blood" is still in it is not one of them.

Comment: I guess they haven't heard of the apostle paul?

Comment: -1 as most of this answer (why such a belief would be wrong) is off-topic.

Comment: @ThaddeusB - sorry you think explanation is off-topic

Comment: @warren I don't think "explanation" if off-topic.  I think giving an opinion opposite of the requested perspective is off-topic.  What you think about the "problem with this stance" is not an answer to the question "who holds this view?"

Comment: http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/161086/observing-torah-like-jesus  Good info here on warrens answer

Comment: @ThaddeusB - it's not an *opinion*, it's a fact: claiming you are eating blood when consuming rare steak is false.

Comment: @warren The accuracy of your information is not the issue. The issue is that "they are wrong because" is not an answer to "who believes this?"

Comment: @ThaddeusB - it's additional information that addresses part of the issue *in addition to* the "who believes this" aspect