# Can a Christian eat semi cooked or red-blood running meat?

Tags: animals

Can Christians Today, eat semi-cooked or blood running red meat?

Comment: I don't think this question is the same.  The bible indicates that a Christian should avoid eating meat with blood in it and animals that were strangled.  This is New Testament, not Old Testament.  The question is not about Kosher food laws which include much more than that.  The questions it especially relevant to Sola Scripture adherents.

Comment: This question would be much better if you distinguish it from the other question, and relate it to the Jerusalem council.

Comment: Try looking at https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46207/what-does-it-mean-to-abstain-from-blood-in-the-21st-century  also

Comment: @Kris That is a good article, and probably the most similar to this question. However, I believe that this question has a separate focus that is only covered briefly in that one answer. I would like to hear more how others would answer this specifically.

Comment: Note that what most people consider "red-blood running meat" isn't actually that.  The meat at the supermarket has normally already  been drained of blood, whose haemoglobin makes it look red.  The similar looking red liquid that often runs from red meat isn't blood, which flows through veins etc., but simply liquid that is leaking from the muscle cells.  It looks red because of [myoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoglobin), which is not the same as haemoglobin.