If a Catholic consumes animal blood, through blood sausage or just directly, do they have to go to confession?
I drink animal blood strictly for health reasons. As far as I am concerned, it is integral to being extremely healthy, and not just moderately more healthy than normal. I'm not particularly interested in debating the merits of that perspective here.
What I am interested in is how that affects my Catholic Faith. Some have mentioned that there is a reaffirmed prohibition on the consumption of blood in Catholicism:

Acts 15:20 "abstain from things polluted by idols, from sexual immorality, from things strangled, and from blood."

But the reading of that being literal seems to miss the mark. It seems to be more about the ritualistic or symbolic blood or Cannibalism, rather than say "Korean Blood Sausage" or "Blood Pudding" or drinking that from a freshly butchered animal.
I am not sure if I am prepared to put my personal health below Catholic teaching. If they forced me to be a vegetarian for example, I simply would not convert, or rather I would convert with every intention to break that hypothetical commandment every day. So for Catholics, what are the relevant technicalities to my dilemna here?
If I were to become a Catholic, and then subsequently consumed animal blood for health reasons, would I then have to go to confession? Could I be excommunicated from the church for doing so insolong as my genuine belief was that this was for my health and longevity? Obviously there is blood in a rare steak; but I have not heard that the consumption of this as being a problem in Catholicism. Has this been ruled against officially or included as part of their catechism in any particular context?

To the negative voters, where is the comment on how to improve the question? :(

@Wyrsa, alas, "offensive" Questions also get down-voted. I suspect that is the case, here. (I confess, one is mine, which I've since reconsidered, but SE doesn't permit one to reconsider down-votes until/unless the Question is edited.)

@Matthew I'm very aware that "offensive" questions get downvoted. I have a question about "magic" which of course got that treatment as well.

@Matthew after a question had been edited you can change your dv to a uv

Related lots of good info in answers. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46207/23657

@Kristopher, I already removed my DV; the question is up to only -1 (from -4 at one point).

To my knowledge, the Catholic Church does not forbid drinking animal blood unless it is a participation in a pagan ritual. That said, even if She does, you can appeal to your bishop for a dispensation for heal purposes. None of the Church's dietary restrictions are absolute, though some are generally binding under pain of sin. For a just cause, bishops can always grant a dispensation.

If a Catholic consumes animal blood, through blood sausage or just directly, do they have to go to confession?
The short answer is no.
You will not find this action listed as a sin in any Catholic source as a sin because it is not a sin.
To be crystal clear that this is in no way considered a sin within Catholic doctrine, I personally have eaten blood sausage that was served at the main meal meal in a Catholic Religious Order, and more than once for that matter.
Although I am not a fan of blood products in my diet, I would not refuse to eat it again if it were served to me again.
So though, as an Canadian who didn't grow up consuming foods made with blood, I find the idea of eating blood utterly unappetizing unappealing, it is not forbidden by Catholic moral theology or practice.
Another example might be if When eating a steak rare or well done is a matter of conscience and of taste. What enters the mouth does not make us unclean (see Matthew 15:17-18). Eating black pudding may not appeal to everyone, but it is not a sin. We live under grace. We have liberty in Christ. Others may have different convictions about food and drink, and in that case we voluntarily limit our freedom in order to better serve them and God. “Let us therefore make every effort to do what leads to peace and to mutual edification” (Romans 14:19).
The following article may be of interest to some:

Are Christians Forbidden to Consume Blood?


Oh Ken, you haven't had our bloodwurst :) Should you ever be in the Low Countries, I would strongly recommend you try.

@ABMK I will next time in the neighborhood!

I'm not Catholic, so take my guesses with respect to those aspects of your Question with a grain of salt. However, there is a bigger issue here.

Obviously there is blood in a rare steak.

First off, this is false. This is a myth that is easily dispelled by the most cursory of investigation. If rare steak contained blood, then cooking would not magically remove it; all steak would contain blood. The red liquid from rare stake is not blood.

If I became Catholic, and then subsequently consumed animal blood for health reasons, would I then have to go to confession?

Regardless of the Catholic position on the consumption of animal blood, if it's bothering you, then "yes", you ought to confess it, or at least discuss it with your priest. Anne rightly reminds us that what is fine for one person may be "wrong" for another, as our consciences dictate. That you are asking this question suggests that what you are doing may be "wrong for you" regardless of the official Catholic position.
However, I suspect this may be only a proxy for the real issue...

Could I be excommunicated from the church for doing so insolong as my genuine belief was that this was for my health and longevity?

Regardless of the answer to the above, I believe you may be in danger of being excommunicated. If I were your priest, I would be having a very stern word with you, and excommunication would not be off the table. Why? Let's go back to your earlier statement:

I am not sure if I am prepared to put my personal health below Catholic teaching. If they forced me to be a vegetarian for example, I simply would not convert.

You may be familiar with the First Commandment, "You shall have no other gods before Me".
Idolatry was the first Sin. Adam and Eve ate the fruit out of a desire to be "like God". When you desire "to put [your] personal health" before God's Word, you are in effect saying that you (or other fallible humans) know more than the infinitely wise Creator who designed your body. Surely He knows more about its workings, and how to best care for it, than you or any other human knows. To believe otherwise is to make yourself out to be better than God, to put yourself before God, and is a direct violation of the First Commandment.
The Catholic Church claims to speak with the same authority as Scripture. Therefore, if you are not willing to put their teachings first in your life, you have no business becoming Catholic. I would certainly expect any priest aware of your attitude to wish to redress it.
Now... that said, many Christians reject the Catholic Church's claims to speak with the same authority of Scripture, and at least some don't have a prohibition against consuming animal blood. If you are (or desire to become) Christian, one of those might be a better fit, especially if you believe that the Catholic Church's requirements overstep what is required by Scripture. Nevertheless, I would strongly encourage you to ask yourself whether you are willing to accept what God's Word says is correct behavior on this (or any other) matter.
Personally, while my denomination does not condemn consuming animal blood, I personally believe that God intended for only the ceremonial laws regarding clean and unclean food to be lifted, and that the direction given to Noah (and reiterated by James) is still in force: "Every moving thing that lives shall be food for you. And as I gave you the green plants, I give you everything. But you shall not eat flesh with its life, that is, its blood." (Genesis 9:3-4)

Christ was asked, and he answered; "The fruits produced of a good tree will be good. The fruits produced of a bad tree will be bad. You will know them by their fruits." - I don't think Catholicism could have their claim without renewing that dictum every day, and so what would it say about a faith that prohibitted good fruits and encouraged bad fruits? I'd like to think that they would not be above reform, but its a difficult question to tackle because we are talking about a hypothetical here. There is also the aspect of Israel, where one wrestles with God... shrug Thanks for your answer.

Matthew I looked up basic catholic sites and it feels like you're way off. Food was declared by Christ to not defile you. (Mark 7:14-23)

@Wyrsa, there's a difference between "food" and consuming the life of an animal, especially if one is doing so in the belief that doing so somehow makes that life their own (which starts to look like magick-working). However, the real issue is the attitude with respect to the RCC's authority.

@Anon, I'll note again that I am not Catholic. In general, Protestants aren't going to see anything wrong with the belief that Catholicism has "bad fruits", but as I said, if you feel that way, you probably shouldn't be Catholic (but you can still be Christian). The bigger concern — and I'd encourage you to discuss this with a pastor/priest and not just random people on the internet — is whether you are truly prepared to put God's instructions ahead of all else in your life, or at least to recognize any failures (because none of us are perfect, after all) as sinful.

@Matthew I do not believe that Anon was attempting to perform vampiric magic. Also the issue of respecting your body as the Temple of God is something important to Christians. So if the OP is being honest, then they are obligated by their conscience to do that. I am of course assuming good intent and no shenanigans.

@Wyrsa, one hopes not, but as I'm aware of no medical science to back up Anon's beliefs, one has to wonder at their source. You raise an interesting question, though; if you believe something is good for your health, but is also clearly prohibited by the Orthodox Church, would you do it? Would you argue it's okay, even obligatory to do it? What if you believe it's good for you, but your conscience troubles you over doing it? If you aren't willing to defend your decision to do something, that may suggest that what you're doing is not, in fact, defensible.

@Matthew The orthodox church is not structured like a legal system. Even the very large periods of fasting are voluntary. If you cannot abstain from something, it is not sinful. If you have medical needs, it is not sinful. If you cannot fast before the divine liturgy because you'll go into a coma, come celebrate the liturgy after breakfast! :)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Like yourself, I am not a Catholic, but I have a "Concise Sacramentum Mundi" Catholic encyclopedia, which I consulted to seek an answer to: "If I became Catholic, then subsequently consumed animal blood for health reasons, would I then have to go to confession? Could I be excommunicated from the church for doing so..."
First, there was nothing about diet in the Encyclopedia. Second, there was a helpful section, "Commandments of the Church" which shows why diet (and other personal matters) are not any part of binding commandments. A history of the development of such commandments was detailed as relating to "the salvation of the faithful (canon law)". In time, a difficulty was tackled: "the over-emphasis of obedience lead[s] to a dangerous legalistic morality... to the detriment of higher values... The deeper reason for this legalism is no doubt to be found in a false need of religious security." Also, in time, changes were made regarding "e.g. fasting and the censorship of books". As for the current state of the commandments of the Church, its "immediate object [is] the preservation of public order in the Church." Encyclopedia of Theology, article Commandments of the Church by Waldemar Molinski, pp.270-274, Burns & Oates, 1981.
That is why diet does not come into these Church commandments, much less a personal view on a perceived health need to consume blood. It does not impinge on "the public order of the Church." It could not, therefore be a matter for excommunication. As Catholicism has no objection to persons receiving e.g. whole blood transfusions to save their lives, it may have no objection to ingesting blood via other means, but as I am not a Catholic, the need would be to approach a Catholic authority on that detail. With regard to whether eating/drinking blood would need to be confessed, that would be up to the person, for if their conscience did not trouble them, then they would not even think about confessing the matter.
It may, however, be appropriate to ask for a Catholic explanation of the covenant made with Noah, after the flood, and which is binding on all humanity. The Noachian covenant is between God, Noah and all his descendants (and we are all his descendants through his sons, Shem Ham and Japheth), and all flesh that is upon the earth - Geneses 9:8-16. This includes God's stipulation that the blood of killed animals be drained out before their flesh is eaten. See Genesis 9:3-6 (which seems to put shedding man's blood in acts of murder as an equally reprehensible matter, for which God will judge people.) That would be a question for the Hermeneutics site, not here. (Detail - red liquid in cooked meat, especially if rare, is extra-vascular fluid, not blood.)

As you'll note from my Answer, I disagree with there not being a potential excommunication issue here. The consumption of blood is not the real issue; the real issue is "I am not sure if I am prepared to put my personal health below Catholic teaching", and needs to be addressed. If it isn't, is not willful and unrepentant sin grounds for excommunication?

@Matthew  I noted your disagreement but I did not answer to promote my own views on the matter. I strove to give Catholic information on the issue, and could find no grounds for them saying it should be an excommunication issue; quite to the contrary. And now Ken Graham has given a definitive and authoritative Catholic answer, which I hope will get the green tick.

The noachide law is a prohibition on eating carrion, and implicitly against animal cruelty.

I'm Orthodox, not catholic, however I believe I can share insight on this issue from the catholic perspective. There is a short answer at the bottom.
The members of the Orthodox and Catholic churches consume blood once a week (Even during Lent or other fasting periods).
It is the Eucharist. Both of these churches believe it IS blood.
I have gone into much detail on other questions that ask about "The Law" and "Sacrifices". The short version is that Christ has fulfilled the sacrifices, not replaced, not removed, but rather fulfilled.

The prohibition against eating blood found in the Old Testament was a discipline associated with the covenant between God and Noah, and incorporated into the Mosaic Covenant. When Jesus established the New Covenant through His death and resurrection, the disciplines of the Old Covenant became unnecessary. The discipline was maintained for a brief time in the early Church to protect new converts from scandal, but was not associated with the theological understanding of grace. When taken in context, we find that the consumption of blood is not forbidden and, moreover, it is necessary in the Eucharist. (Catholic Exchange)


Additionally we can literally use the words of Christ Himself.

When He had called all the multitude to Himself, He said to them, “Hear Me, everyone, and understand: There is nothing that enters a man from outside which can defile him; but the things which come out of him, those are the things that defile a man. If anyone has ears to hear, let him hear!”
When He had entered a house away from the crowd, His disciples asked Him concerning the parable. So He said to them, “Are you thus without understanding also? Do you not perceive that whatever enters a man from outside cannot defile him, because it does not enter his heart but his stomach, and is eliminated, thus purifying all foods?” And He said, “What comes out of a man, that defiles a man. For from within, out of the heart of men, proceed evil thoughts, adulteries, fornications, murders, thefts, covetousness, wickedness, deceit, lewdness, an evil eye, blasphemy, pride, foolishness. All these evil things come from within and defile a man.”  (The Gospel according to Mark 7:14-23)


The verse you quoted is referring to idol worshiping, adulterous rituals and pagan practices. Naturally all of those things are still forbidden today, because those practices come from within. See the list above.

You mention a command against drinking blood, but like all of the Old Testament dietary regulations, it has passed away,

“These are only a shadow of what is to come, but the substance belongs to Christ. Therefore let no one pass judgment on you in questions of food and drink” (Col 2:17 & 16 note verse order inverted for emphasis).



The mention of not eating blood in Acts 15:20, 29 was a pastoral provision suggested by James to keep Jews from being scandalized by the conduct of Gentile Christians. We know that these pastoral provisions were only temporary. One concerned abstaining from idol meat, yet later Paul says eating idol meat is okay so long as it doesn’t scandalize others (Rom 14:1-14, 1 Cor 8:1-13). (Catholic.com)


The Old Testament is very specific about why one was not to eat blood: “The life of every creature is the blood of it; therefore I have said to the people of Israel, You shall not eat the blood of any creature, for the life of every creature is its blood” (Lv 17:14, cf. Dt 12:23). The Israelites could not eat animal blood because it contained the animal’s life.
However, as a Christian you are supposed to have the life of Christ within you. "I am the way, the truth, and the life, no one comes to the father except through me" (John 14:6)

Short Answer:
The words from Christ (Mark 7:14-23) are that you are perfectly fine to eat ANYTHING. Because it is not what you eat, but what comes from within you that will defile you.

"The members of the Orthodox and Catholic churches consume blood once a week" this is an equivocation that really just obscures the meaning of the question. This person is asking about consuming animal blood, as prohibited in Acts 15. The is a very obvious different between the Blood of our Lord in the Eucharist and the blood of dumb animals taken as ordinary drink.

@jaredad7 I don't think it is an equivocation. It is blood, as an orthodox I do not know how it becomes blood, I do not know why sometimes it tastes like wine and sometimes it tastes more like a rare steak... The verse in Acts 15 I believe is referring to the pagan practices. See some of the answers here https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/91300/why-did-james-advise-abstaining-from-blood-in-acts-1529

I am convinced, being fully persuaded in the Lord Jesus, that nothing is unclean in itself. But if anyone regards something as unclean, then for that person it is unclean. If your brother or sister is distressed because of what you eat, you are no longer acting in love. Do not by your eating destroy someone for whom Christ died. (Romans 14:14-15 NIV)

It is an equivocation because we are talking about the Blood of the God Man hidden in forms of Bread and Wine, vs the blood of beasts under its ordinary, natural form, with no supernatural activity involved. I'm not saying that it is a sin to drink animal blood. As you point out, Scripture says all things are clean for consumption.

I dislike the use of the word "hidden" in the way you say that. Catholics and Orthodox both believe it "IS" the body and blood of Christ. That is to say, meat and blood. The fact that this meat and blood is that of Christ doesn't negate any of the other laws. Not even the ones given to Noah. Afterall Christ fulfilled the Law not abolished. What I'm trying to say is that Christ's blood, is blood. Animal blood, is also blood. On that level it is not wrong to say that. After all, when I go to divine liturgy I believe it is Blood and I don't understand why it is Blood. Such are the Mysteries.

Hidden is a fine term used by good Catholic theologians. It does not mean that there are mere symbols, but that the reality is hidden to our sense. Aquinas writes poetically "Praestet fides supplementum/Sensuum defectui." in English "Faith for all defects supplying/Where the feeble senses fail." The point, however, is that the Divine Blood in essence is certainly different from mere human blood (because it is united to the Divine Essence in the Person of Christ) and furthermore is especially distinct from animal blood (which is not even united to a nature bearing the Image of God).

Fair point. I think I'm guilty of just quibbling about phrasing.
